# passing variables to batch from VBScript

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I've got this code in vbscript that launches a batch script with some arguments.

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "printTR.bat " & jsfunction() & " " & amount & " " & printer
```

The problem is, sometimes the `jsfunction()` has spaces, so as you could see the 2nd word would be counted as nother variable. I've tried things like `""" & jsfunction() & """"` and `""" & jsfunction() & """`, which stopped the script from working at all.

The `jsfunction()` is basically just a return of a user input field in the same page. It could contain anything that can be typed on a keyboard.

How can I pass the variable as a single string?

Comment: I disagree with the close requests as I have given all the information I know how to gather about the issue. I'm not asking why the code isn't working, and I provided the steps I tried to fix it and the code causing problems.

Comment: So we are just supposed to guess what `jsfunction()` does as [Alex has done in their answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42166692/692942)? - *"assuming `jsfunction()` does not itself return a string that contains quotes"*. So, because you don't provide enough information people are left to second guess you.

Comment: @Lankymart I didn't know that was important. That could have easily been asked in the comments and I would have added it to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "printTR.bat """ & jsfunction() & """ " & amount & " " & printer
```

Is the correct way to pass the string with quotes (assuming `jsfunction()` does not itself return a string that contains quotes) .

If that fails perhaps its because the batch file now also received the string with quotes (`echo %1` would return `"a quoted string"`) where is does not expect to, to rectify this use `%~1` which is the same string but without quotes.